# How can I render events on fullcalendar after the calendar has been loaded completely?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I have a form that the user need to fill. After the form has been submitted the user is redirected to another page where the fullcalendar appear. I want to load the calendar completely, do some calculations with the data from the form and after each calculation echo an event on the calendar. My calculation takes a lot of time that's why I want the events to appear on the calendar one by one as the calculation proceeds (so that the user can see events that are ready in the meantime). I want to place the PHP codes outside the events:[] so that the calendar is loaded completely and then I echo the events one-by-one on the calendar. Please help me !!!

Here is the code:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,listWeek,agendaDay'
                },
                theme : true,
                titleFormat : 'MMMM D YYYY',
                columnFormat: 'dddd D',
                allDaySlot : false,
                slotDuration : '00:15:00',
                minTime : '07:00:00',
                firstDay : 1,
                /*eventOverlap : false,*/
                defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
                navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
                editable: true,
                eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
                timeFormat: 'H:mm',

                events: [
                    <?php
                      // After each calculation echo an event
                        echo
                            " {".
                            "id:". "'$id',".
                            "title:". "'$title'". ','.
                            "start:" . "'$date". "T".  "$ActStartTime'" .','.
                            "end:" .  "'$date". "T".  "$ActEndTime'".
                            "}, "
                        ;
                    ?>
                ]
            });

        });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a combination of the following two would do the trick:

1. Make a [event feed](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/) that returns your events. That means you provide a REST resource (new php script that loops through already calculated events and echos them in the [event object](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/) format) and add the URL as feed.
2. Trigger the [refetchEvents](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/refetchEvents/) method every few seconds or whatever interval seems fitting.

This is not the most elegant solution but it seems easy to implement. A better solution would be to have a REST resource that only returns the new events and not the already rendered ones. Then you would just retrieve them in your own ajax function and add them to the already existing ones, but that would need a bit more implementation.

I hope this helps, if not feel free to comment and clarify :)

Comment: Not sure how to implement this

Comment: I want to send each event information from a PHP script to ajax but the problem is that ajax can only receive a result and then it is over

Comment: That's why you need to send multiple requests via ajax to your php script. Either you send a request every few seconds to ask if new events have been calculated or if you know for examples the event ids you can send a request for each id: /getEvent.php?id=123